# Использование php переменных в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли в mysql запросе вместо таблицы указать переменную php?

Eсли можно, то как?

```
"SELECT name FROM '$table' WHERE id='$i'"
```

Не работает.

Comment: Вы полностью покажите код, как объявляете переменную `$table`, как запрос собираете, и какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: $table = "program";

Comment: Покажи весь код + ошибки, которые он выдает.....И только не говори, что не выдает)

Comment: Оно конечно так работает, но делать так _нельзя_. Это влечет за собой SQL-инъекции и взлом вашего сайта. _Всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые запросы и привязку параметров http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать переменные можно, в вашем случае скорее всего ошибка в синтаксисе самом MySQL, название таблицы нужно оборачивать в другой символ - `` ` ``,а не в одинарную ковычку `'`.

В символ `'` оборачивают значения.

А вот в символ `` ` `` оборачивают названия колонок и таблиц.

Ваш запрос должен выглядеть вот так:

```
"SELECT `name` FROM `$table` WHERE `id`='$i'"
```

Но учтите что это не безопасно, используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) для запросов к базе данных, к примеру ваш запрос выглядел бы правильно вот так:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=3306;dbname=$db;user=$user;password=$pass");
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `$table` WHERE `id` = :id");
$sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Вы так же в своих работах запросы составляете?

Comment: @Mike дополнил ответ, думаю теперь лучше выглядит